# Gradle Debug and launch app

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Can't see any documentation of a command that will install and launch the app or debug the app.

Currently only *installDebug* or *installRelease* the app.

Anyone know how can I launch the app? Or debug the app with breakpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any one know how i can launch the app?

There is no Gradle for Android task that will launch an app. You are welcome to write yourself a custom task, that depends upon `installDebug`, that uses **`adb shell am start`** or something to start an activity of your choice.

> Or debug the app with breakpoints?

Gradle for Android does not have a debugger. An IDE, like Android Studio, has a debugger.

Comment: Yeah i just switched to android studio its a lot better